# FLASH AS3 - How to increase noise in a motion detector using webcam?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam, augmented-reality

I am able to detect motion through webcam but with help of soulwire webcam-motion-detection-tracking tutorial,.

The problem is it reacts to every small motion, I wish to increase the minimum motion for it to react.

Any help or any direction on what can be done will be great.

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: Send a link to that tutorial or paste some code. How can we know what's the issue? :)

Comment: http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/webcam-motion-detection-tracking

this is the link to the tutorial, its helping big time in motion detection, i want to reduce the threshold a bit so that, while detecting a hand motion it ignores the elbow or shoulder(offcourse small movements of shoulder n elbow to be ignored)

Comment: Check out this line (103): `_now.threshold(_now, _now.rect, new Point(), '>', 0xFF333333, 0xFFFFFFFF);`. It's a bit difficult to modify this, as it's a 'use it as is' solution. You can also check the `minArea` property, but I'm not sure it will work in your case. Treshold is your best buddy :)